# Are you notified when you fail a review audit?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, review-audits

While reviewing, I just passed one of the test answers that's put in to make sure you're paying attention.

> This was only a test, designed to make sure you were paying attention.
>   You passed. Downvoting, editing, or flagging as "very low quality" are
>   all appropriate actions in this case.

I've seen this a few times, but I've never seen the opposite telling me I've failed to notice one of these. Are you notified if you miss one of these, or are you just quietly taken off the review queue for a while?

Secondarily, does skipping one of these example tests (because they're about a subject I don't understand, for example) count as a fail?

Comment: Yep a pop up will appear when you fail a review with information to help explain what you did wrong (or at least what the system thinks you did wrong)

Comment: just by reading the title I figured that asker _never_ [failed an audit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/178897/165773 "that 'STOP! Look and Listen...', followed by a looooong pause, is simply impossible to forget")

Comment: @gnat - I've not actually done that many, but I'm pleased nonetheless.

Comment: And I thought it was a bug when I got the "This was only a test, designed to make sure you were paying attention. **You passed.**" message twice in close succession ...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're notified immediately whether you pass or fail a review audit. Skipping a review audit does not count either in your favor or against you, as far as I know. It should always be safe to hit the Skip button when you don't know what to do. (I hit it a lot, so I think I'd get review banned a lot if it counted against us.)

Comment: Before anyone asks, yes, moderators *can* get review banned.

Comment: at which page / date of [your reviews list](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1288/bill-the-lizard?tab=activity&sort=reviews) can one see a break caused by a ban? or moderators can unban themselves?

Comment: @gnat I don't keep track. There are a lot of breaks in my reviewing activity, but only two are from bans. One was recent, but the other was months ago. Moderators cannot unban themselves from review bans that I'm aware of.

Comment: two bans in over 18K close reviews, not bad. You seem to review attentively

Comment: @gnat I blame poorly selected review audit posts for one of those. ;) I can't claim that I don't make mistakes though, so the other one is on me.

Comment: totally agree wrt poor selection of audits. Note me and you probably don't fully know how bad it is, as some (maybe _many_) of wrong audits could be "manually corrected" by prior reviewers. BTW it would be interesting to learn stats on how many "known good" close audits eventually end up being voted down and close

Comment: and even if you make no mistakes, some of the reviews are flawed and the correct answer gets you to fail it. Or the review makes no sense, fails you improperly. Had it happen I just wanted to leave a comment on a post I was reviewing and leave it open, the "test" failed me for incorrectly trying to close the post.